# how to correct initial value NA that generates diff

Tags: r

when I use the diff function of type xts objects.

Well I'm trying to convert a **non-stationary data** source to **stationary**, if anyone has any other method please would appreciate your help

```r
diff.xts(tb_xts$col1,log = F)

2012-12-01  NA      #  <-- correct this
2012-12-06  -0.211416877
2012-12-16  0.2005834963
```

is there any other way to correct the initial value?, 
I know that by default the diff starts from the second element

Comment: maybe set `na.pad=FALSE`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 what happens is that I don't want to lose elements

Comment: then you can also set NA to the value that you want

Comment: It's the `diff` between actual and previous element, what else do you expect the first value to be than `NA`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid this NA, but I already solved it by saving the first element and then make a calculation and store it in the NA